# NVIDIA GFORCE 610M drivers

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I'm attempting to install drivers for my GFORCE 610M and none of the solutions seems to work. Generally people recommend using the jockey-gtk program, which doesn't detect the card and states that there's no propitiatory drivers to install. I tried download the official binary from the NVIDIA site, but that told me that I had to remove the Nouveau kernal driver, so I did that, following the instructions on the wiki (apt-get remove --purge xorg-something or other) and ignoring the "DON'T DO THIS" warning, after that didn't do anything i installed various packages (nvidia-common, nvidia-settings, etc) and eventually got the nvidia-settings program (and a very low screen resolution). Unfortunately when I open nvidia-settings it tells me to run nvidia-xconfig as root (i've done this several times, but to no avail) and doesn't let me configure anything. At this point I tried re-running the binary installer i downloaded from nvidia's site, and it said it worked but it didn't change a thing. So I'm out of ideas, what've you got?

Comment: Why do you want to install an additional driver anyway? Doesn't work without?

Comment: My main reason was that Gnome Shell looked like Gnome Classic due to lack of video drivers (I suspected, and have now confirmed), but also that games were simply unplayable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, but I had to do a full reinstall. On a clean copy of Ubuntu 12.04 desktop, following instruction on a page I can't find anymore I first purged the existing nvidia-current:

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current`

Then added the [bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/) repository:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`

Then updated and installed bumblebee:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia`

After a reboot everything worked nicely

Comment: If you have an nVidia optimus graphics card, you should have said that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going to "Additional Drivers", and activating the post-release updates? It contains the NVIDIA driver 295.49, I believe -- the one for that card.

Comment: No, where is that located? Additional Drivers just has Close, Help and a greyed out Enable button, looks like [this](https://imgur.com/X03Qt)

Comment: jockey-gtk and 'Additional Drivers" are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the terminal and enter this command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

This will install the proper driver for your hardware.  When it is finished, please just restart and everything should work fine.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. I tried a ton of stuff and eventually messed my system up beyond repair (IMO), and reinstalled Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

if this is a problem for ubuntu read under :

to install nvidia gt 610m driver for ubuntu 12.10 :

first remove nvidai driver :

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current && sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current-update
```

Then :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

For Ubuntu 12.04 or earlier :

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current && sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current-update
```

Then :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

Good luck

Comment: You should try terminal commands as code rather than bold. It makes it much easier to read.

Comment: Does this solution offer some way to switch on the GPU? From what I've heard that requires bumblebee at this point (see the solution I posted)

Answer (score 0):

Bumblebee isn't the good driver for nVidia 610M

Best for list in the following link: [LinuxSeason](http://linuxseason.ir/wp-content/uploads/NVDA_Optimus_Platforms.jpg)

I've installed it and my graphics card is an nVidia GT610M didn't work well.